# Angular show/hide working only on second function call, apply/digest issue?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have the following in a controller, which is designed to show the content after it's loaded. Should in theory be pretty simple but is not playing ball, so I'm trying to understand what I'm doing wrong. This is for a view containing an ionic slide box which is what I'm trying to hide until the data is loaded, and with an ion-refresher for pull to refresh, hence the `$scope.broadcast('scroll.refreshComplete');`

```
    //initial controller vars:
    $scope.data = {};
    $scope.data.loading = true;
    $scope.data.user = 1;
    $scope.data.week = {};

    $scope.data.getContent = function() {
            var now = new Date().getTime();
            serverRequestFactory.getWeek(now)
            .success(function(response){
                    $scope.data.week = response;
                    $scope.data.loading = false;
                    $ionicSlideBoxDelegate.update();
                    $scope.$broadcast('scroll.refreshComplete');
                    })
            .error(function(response){
                   $scope.data.loading = false;
                   $scope.$broadcast('scroll.refreshComplete');
                   })
            }

            if($scope.data.user == 1){
            //calls above on view load
                $scope.data.getContent();
                //$scope.data.getContent();
            }
```

The weird thing is the above works if I uncomment the second call to `$scope.data.getContent()` but I don't know why. I've tried `$scope.apply()` both before and after setting the $scope.data.week object and the update of the slide box delegate. Where's my error?

**EDIT**: So I just added an ng-repeat directive to one of the slide box items:

```
<ion-slide-box on-slide-changed="slideHasChanged($index)" ng-hide="data.loading">
            <ion-slide class="customSlidePadding" ng-repeat="item in data.week.items">
```

And now the entire slide box respects the initial ng-hide value and shows up without a second function call... There surely has to be an *angular* reason adding the directive to a nested item in the hidden slide box makes it work?

Comment: How are you initially calling `getContent` within the template or initialization of the controller?

Comment: In the initialisation of the controller, the data arrives as it should, I can log it to the console, but the loading false is not reflected in the view.

Comment: Any chance you can create a plunkr/jsfiddle for this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using $scope.data.week on your view you should initialize it, otherwise angular does not create $watch over it after the first call.

Just do.

```js
$scope.data.week = []; //or whatever data you want...
```

you should do this before calling the async request.

Comment: Again, if it is an object you should add mocked data for all its members. for example $scope.data.week = { first: { monday: 1, so on.. }, second: {..}, this is the best way to work with data that is not an array. You should always start your controller with mocked data (unless the variable is an array,).

Comment: Though this issue is to do with the $scope.data.loading boolean not being reflected in the view which is set before the async call...

Comment: So you have something like ng-hide=$scope.data.loading and this is not working properly?

Comment: yes, ng-hide="data.loading" does not work on the first call of getContent

Answer (score 0):

Unless your template is actually calling your function via an event handler

```
on-event="data.getContent()"
```

or via some binding mechanism (which I don't recommend)

```
<p>{{data.getContent()}}
```

Then you aren't actually calling this method.  Nothing I've seen in the supplied code is actually calling this, you've only defined the method which calls itself in the *if* block.

Try explicitly calling it:

```
$scope.data.getContent = function() {
        var now = new Date().getTime();
        serverRequestFactory.getWeek(now)
        .success(function(response){
                $scope.data.week = response;
                $scope.data.loading = false;
                $ionicSlideBoxDelegate.update();
                $scope.$broadcast('scroll.refreshComplete');
                })
        .error(function(response){
               $scope.data.loading = false;
               $scope.$broadcast('scroll.refreshComplete');
               })
        }

        if($scope.data.user == 1){
        //calls above on view load
            $scope.data.getContent();
            //$scope.data.getContent();
        }
}

//explicitly calling
$scope.data.getContent();
```

Comment: It's definitely being called, I'm logging the success response to the console which happens each time the view loads... trying what you suggested called it twice, two logs in the console, two server requests... though the content is actually shown on the second request. That's what I don't get...

Comment: Without seeing more of the code and template I'm not entirely sure how else to help.  As suggested in my other comment to the question, try recreating this in a jsfiddle or plunker.  You can easily mock the service request if need be by using $timeout and $q.  I have a hunch that either you're missing something totally obvious (which happens to us all) or you're consuming something incorrectly on the UI.

Comment: I've tried to recreate this in a fiddle, it just works as expected :/ I've got a feeling theres some issue with cordova or ionic's js on the slide box or something as this is the initial view after app load.

Comment: I know nothing of Cordova or Ionic's setup but is there a chance that their directives are expecting a promise to consume as a data source?  Kinda like how ui.bootstrap's Typeahead can use a promise as an async-source for its data providers.  Also have you tried using `$timeout` to call the initial `$scope.data.getContent()`.  Sorry we're not much help on this.